# How to make the bot reply with multiple action rows in DiscordJS?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to make a Discord bot using DiscordJS, that can do a TicTacToe game, but I don't know how to add 3 rows of button below the bot's reply.

I already made 3 buttons row:

```
const row1 = new ActionRowBuilder()
            .addComponents(new ButtonBuilder().setCustomId("00").setLabel(" ").setStyle(ButtonStyle.Primary))
            .addComponents(new ButtonBuilder().setCustomId("01").setLabel(" ").setStyle(ButtonStyle.Primary))
            .addComponents(new ButtonBuilder().setCustomId("02").setLabel(" ").setStyle(ButtonStyle.Primary))
const row2 = new ActionRowBuilder()
            .addComponents(new ButtonBuilder().setCustomId("10").setLabel(" ").setStyle(ButtonStyle.Primary))
            .addComponents(new ButtonBuilder().setCustomId("11").setLabel(" ").setStyle(ButtonStyle.Primary))
            .addComponents(new ButtonBuilder().setCustomId("12").setLabel(" ").setStyle(ButtonStyle.Primary))
const row3 = new ActionRowBuilder()
            .addComponents(new ButtonBuilder().setCustomId("20").setLabel(" ").setStyle(ButtonStyle.Primary))
            .addComponents(new ButtonBuilder().setCustomId("21").setLabel(" ").setStyle(ButtonStyle.Primary))
            .addComponents(new ButtonBuilder().setCustomId("22").setLabel(" ").setStyle(ButtonStyle.Primary))
```

Here's the bot's reply (that only has 1 row).

```
await interaction.reply({
            content:`**TicTacToe**.`,
            components:[row1],
          });
```

The reply should have 3 rows below the message.

Comment: Add `row2` and `row3` to the array? Like `components:[row1, row2, row3]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add row 1, 2 and 3 as an array like so:

```js
await interaction.reply({
            content:`**TicTacToe**.`,
            components:[row1, row2, row3],
          });
```

Please see [this](https://discordjs.guide/interactions/buttons.html#building-and-sending-buttons) on action rows with buttons